Print Job Management
I know this sort of product exists as I have used it in the past, but it was pretty niche then and no one else I knew had heard of it.
Broadly speaking I am looking for print job management software, with the following specific features:

Client only. While it could route jobs to a server-shared printer, it doesn't care about where the printer is, or that there is one or not.
Delay or Batch printing. It can hold print jobs queued until I choose to send them to the printer.
Multi-routing. The software can, if I wish, send all jobs to a printer AND save them as PDFs, at the same time.
Shows as a printer. The software works by being the default printer on the computer, capturing all jobs printed, and then allows merging, sorting, declining, duplicating, and a variety of other functions before you send the jobs to their actual printing destinations.

I believe that PaperCut does something similar to this, but not precisely. The software I recall using was relatively old when I used it, 8-11 years ago, but was still updated occasionally by the developer. Back then I know I found an alternative software product that did the same thing, but I am drawing blanks on the names or the broad category term for both these tools.
